# Bibliograpghy in Lyx

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am trying to get my bibliography in this sytle:

```
[#] Last or first name, First or last name, Title , Publisher, Year.
```

I write the name as:

> Carl Kingsford

But it appears as :

> C. Kingsford

URL does not appear when it has. I want all the information i enter inside jabref to appear in a format (I don't care which), but should appear consistently in all.

Bibtex code:

```
@Book{Observers,

  title     = {Introduction to dynamic systems; theory, models, and applications},

  publisher = {John Wiley and Sons},

  year      = {1979},

  author    = {Luenberger, David G David G},

}
```

Entry:

> [8] D. G. D. G. Luenberger. Introduction to dynamic systems; theory, models, and applications. John Wiley and Sons, 1979.

i am using `abbrv` style, if you guys can suggest me a style.

Example2:

```
@Book{Discretetime,

  title     = {Discrete-time signal processing},

  publisher = {Pearson Higher Education},

  year      = {2010},

  author    = {Oppenheim, Alan V and Schafer, Ronald W},

  edition   = {2nd},

}
```

Comment: You would need a bibliography style that keeps these things.

Comment: You've set the 'biblatex' tag: Please tell us with which options you're loading the `biblatex` package. Please also show us the bibliographic entry: Is the author listed as `Carl Kingsford` or as `C. Kingsford`?

Comment: Incidentally, an aspect of the formatting instructions is rather ambigous: How should one interpret `Last or first name, First or last name`? I can think of (at least) two ways to interpret it. Moreover, it doesn't actually state one way or another if the full or the abbreviated form of the given name should be used.

Comment: I tried a lot of style, But I want [#] style with all the details i have entered in the code. Check the edited question for the bibtex entry

Comment: @Mico: Sorry it was a too vague sentence. What i mean is i don't care if it starts with  last name and first name. But It should maintain the consistency.

Comment: My guess is that you are using only `bibtex`, not `biblatex` (that can be used in LyX, but  setting is not trivial). The style of the bibliography determine if the  name is abbreviated or not,  what part of the appear first, as well as if some fields as the URL are showed or not. You options are a) search the appropriate BibTeX  style b) make your own custom BibTeX style   c) switch to biblatex  and c.1) find a appropriate style and/or c.2) tune it via biblatex options.

Comment: 1) is there any style which you are aware of which suits the requirement? 2) How do i make my custom bibtex style?

Comment: @Aashu10 1) your requirements are not completely clear for me and there are many thing to fix in a bib style . It could help a more complete example of the bibtex code, including also an article reference, URL fields, etc.  and the *desired* output.   2) Use [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package for your own bibtex styles, but at the end  could be better switch to `biblatex` if you are not comfortable with any standard bibtex style.

Comment: @Fran, I mostly don't have a URL. Becuase I try hard to quote a book/article. I have added one more example. Can you please tell me how to switch to biblatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want BibTeX to abbreviate the given names of authors, *don't use the `abbrv` bibliography style*. Instead, use the `plain` style. I.e., change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `abbrv` to `plain`.

From a separate comment, I gather that you want the information given in the entries' `url` fields to be typeset. I therefore suggest that you (a) use the `plainnat` bibliography style and (b) load the package `natbib` with the option `numbers`.

Incidentally, the `author` field of one of your entries is likely incorrect. Instead of

```
author    = {Luenberger, David G David G},
```

it should almost certainly [!] be

```
author    = {Luenberger, David G.},
```

---

A full MWE and its output. Note that the test entries you provided don't have `url` fields.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@Book{Observers,
  title     = {Introduction to Dynamic Systems: Theory, Models, and Applications},
  publisher = {John Wiley and Sons},
  year      = {1979},
  author    = {Luenberger, David G.},
}
@Book{Discretetime,
  title     = {Discrete-time Signal Processing},
  publisher = {Pearson Higher Education},
  year      = {2010},
  author    = {Oppenheim, Alan V. and Schafer, Ronald W.},
  edition   = {2nd},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\cite{Observers}, \cite{Discretetime}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```